# Django rest freamework: get a path parameter in the serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, parameter-passing

I request to a service with this path:

```
/api/story_step/<chatbot>/<story_name>/
```

And in the suitable Django serializer I have the following field:

```
interaction_name = serializers.CharField(source='interaction.name', read_only=True)
```

Which is a reference to another table field:

```
interaction = models.ForeignKey('interactions.Interaction', models.CASCADE, 'story_interaction', 'story_interaction')
```

Is there any way to filter that field by the path parameter  in order to see only the interactions of that defined chatbot?

I mean, in the swagger UI appear the following field:

[image: Referenced field]

And in that list appears all the interactions, from that chatbot and others.

Comment: what model are you using for your serializer? Does it have `chatbot`, and `story_name` fields?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use your path parameters `<chatbot>` and `query_name` for filtering your model to display interactions. You can do something like :

```
class YourAPI(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    model = YourModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        chatbot = self.kwargs.get('chatbot')
        story_name=self.kwargs.get('story_name')
        return self.model.objects.filter(chatbot=chatbot,story_name=story_name)
```

I do not know the name of your Serializer and your Model, so substitute them for `serializer_class` and `model`. This will filter the model based on your path parameters, and display the related `interaction` field results. Of course you can use only one of the parameters for filtering, depending on your code logic (I assumed you need both). You may also use other view classes or ViewSets which provide similar `get` functionality.

Comment: The problem is filter in the Serializer, no in the APIView, because in the swagger appear a list with all the interactions, not only with the suitable chatbot. I mean, I want to filter the options that the swagger offers to me in the API UI.

Comment: Serializer does not perform filtering on its own (it does not know what to filter). If you need to display results for the desired chatbot, you need to filter the queryset in the API based on your chatbot parameter, and let the Serializer return results for your filtered queryset.

Comment: The problem is that the view already filters the results with a queryset. The problem is not the result of the serializer, it's the list of choices in the related field on the swagger UI.